# Managing sessions in Go

Tags: session, go, session-cookies

Are there some Go libraries for sessions?

Using Python/Django there wasn't any problem.

I am new to Go and I haven't found anything about it. So, are there general sessions support for Go? Are there some frameworks with sessions support? (It seems web.go has no sessions support, doesn't it?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Gorilla's sessions package](http://gorilla-web.appspot.com/pkg/gorilla/sessions/) is the one I use and I guess the best choice for most projects. Gorilla also offers a lower-level package, [securecookie](http://gorilla-web.appspot.com/pkg/gorilla/securecookie/).

Other options include [seshcookie](https://github.com/bpowers/seshcookie) and [authcookie](https://github.com/dchest/authcookie).